# MPI rank process

Tags: mpi

I am an MPI beginner, so I 'd like to know exactly the definition of rank of an MPI program, and why we need it

For example, there are 2 lines of code here:

```
int world_rank;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand this, you need to realise that MPI uses the SPMD (Single Program Multiple Data) model. This means that if you run this program in parallel, e.g. on 4 processes at the same time, every process runs its own independent copy of the same program. So, the basic question is: why doesn't every process do the same thing? To make use of parallel programming, you need processes to do different things. For example, you might want one process to act as a controller sending jobs to multiple workers. The rank is the fundamental identifier for each process. If run on 4 processes, then the above program would return ranks of 0, 1, 2 and 3 on the different processes. Once a process knows its rank it can then act appropriately, e.g. "if my rank is zero then call the controller function else call the worker function".

Comment: We also have "MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &n)" in which "n" is the number of process in group of Comm. So does it mean that 1rank can have more than one process or only 1 rank identify only for 1 process ? And than why do we have these integers non-initialized a value